# "true" is an invalid value for the "ShouldUnsetParentConfigurationAndPlatform" parameter of the "AssignProjectConfiguration" task

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, msbuild

**Error:**

`"true" is an invalid value for the "ShouldUnsetParentConfigurationAndPlatform" parameter of the "AssignProjectConfiguration" task. The "ShouldUnsetParentConfigurationAndPlatform" parameter is of type "System.Boolean"`

**Dotnet version**

```
C:\Users\Stefan>dotnet --version
5.0.201
```

**Project Errors**

[image]

All the projects in the solution have target framework net5.0:

```
<TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
```

I've tried restarting Visual Studio, Workstation, cleared bin/obj, cleared resharper cache.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved by installing latest updates for Visual Studio. Not sure what was the problem.